# How to include a java page in asp.net response?

Tags: java, .net, architecture

I am using an asp.net webapp for a business application. I need to address a new requirement which requires this webapp to

1. Share user context with a third party java webapp.
2. Include java webapp page response as part of .net app response.

How do i achieve this? I cannot use an iframe in my .net response because if i do, the user's browser will have to send a request for the java webapp - it has to be a server side include/ forward. The only solution i can think of at this point is opening a url connection on server side to the java webapp and posting data to it, but what i dont like abt this solution is that it is not very scalable.

Comment: To be fair, the new requirement isn't very scalable either.  Good luck though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a java application (packaged in jar), you can use [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net)  to convert that into .NET dll or exe that can be used in .NET web or windows application.

Java files are compiled through javac.exe and run through java.exe, now in order to invoke these two exe you need to use System.Diagnostics.Process class and pass the java file (to javac.exe for compiling) or class file (to java.exe to run the application) as a parameter to Process class

http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ProcessStart.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx

Go through the given [tutorial](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/tutorial.html) at IKVM website.

Also see this [Java.NET : Integration of Java and .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26144/Java-NET-Integration-of-Java-and-NET)

Comment: what I have is a WAR, not a JAR. War has to be deployed on a server that supports Java Servlet Spec.

Comment: IKVM sounds good, but I don't think it applies to my context.